# How to handle button in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new learner..

Write a complete code to show a Toast containing text from the EditText when the button is clicked. Assume in the xml file, EditText xml id=’MyEditText’ and button xml id=’MyButton’.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button myButton = findViewById(R.id.MyButton);
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.MyEditText);

myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                       Toast.makeText(this, editText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you please help me this one also............Assume you have two activities, the first contains a button called "go" and an EditText called "name". The second activity contains only a TextView called "result". When the button is clicked you should move to the second activity and display what's is written in the EditText on the TextView.

Comment: Ah sure, so, to move between activities you can use intents, it would look something like this:                                                                                                                               Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class); startActivity(intent); finish(); Here, the intent is responsible for starting the new activity and startActivity() starts the new activity specified in the intent. finish() removes the current activity from the stack.

Comment: Now, you have to take the editText string with you to the next activity, you can do that by simply adding one more line to the above code: Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);  intent.putExtra("ANY NAME", editText.getText().toString()); startActivity(intent); finish();

Comment: Now, in the receiving activity, you just need to add the following line: String intentString = getIntent().getStringExtra("ANY NAME"); Now you can set the string to the textView. result.setText(intentString).

Comment: so first i have to create a second activity and then in the first activity page i have to initialized this ...

Comment: Yeah, two separate activities, and the intent is used to move from one activity to the other.

Comment: if you don't mind can you give me some suggestion about some side where i can learn and easy to understand the android ..